# why won't my counter count properly ? it adds +1 although my if statement isnt filled

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, count, counter

So my counter is supposed to not count +1 for the string `":DD"` that's why I wrote that only if the length of my string is `2` the counter should add +1. But it adds +1 although the string length is 3.  Why is that?

P.S.: I've put `length() <=3` in the first `if` statement, for another `else if` that comes after the 2nd `if` statement.

```java
int counter = 0;
String tgt = ":DD";

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    if (tgt.length() <= 3 && tgt.charAt(0) == ':' || tgt.charAt(0) == ';') {
        if (tgt.length() == 2 &&  
            tgt.charAt(1) == ')' || tgt.charAt(1) == 'D') {
                counter += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is doing what it's supposed to do, the length of :DD is three and thus the <= will trigger, then for the second if the letter at spot 2 is a D so it will also be true.

Comment: It is happening because of `tgt.charAt(1) == 'D'`. Your condition in second 'if' is `a&&b||c`, which will be true if 'c' is true.

Comment: Why the loop? You aren’t using the value of `i`, so you could delete the loop and use `counter += a.size();` to get the same result. Did you mean to use `tgt.char(i)` where you have coded `tgt.char(1)`?

Comment: i've changed the code a little to make my issue more understandable xD i actually do use the value of i for tgt. tgt is not ":DD" per se but a.get(i) because im checking every element of an array :) thanks for the comment tho :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||`, messing up your intended logic.

The [Java operators page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) lists Java operators in order of precedence.

Because of this, it's as if parentheses are around the two `&&` operands:

```
if ((tgt.length() <= 3 && tgt.charAt(0) == ':') || tgt.charAt(0) == ';')
{
    if ((tgt.length() == 2 &&  tgt.charAt(1) == ')') || tgt.charAt(1) == 'D')
```

In the second `if` condition, the `&&` may return false, but the second (index 1) character is `'D'`, so the whole condition is `true` and your counter gets updated.

Place explicit parentheses around your `||` operands, which is what I think you intended.

```
if (tgt.length() <= 3 && (tgt.charAt(0) == ':' || tgt.charAt(0) == ';'))
{
    if (tgt.length() == 2 && (tgt.charAt(1) == ')' || tgt.charAt(1) == 'D'))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a case [operator precedence (source: `oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) not matching with the expectations we as developers might have. The `&&`-operator has a higher precedence than `||`. This means that

```
tgt.length() <= 3 && tgt.charAt(0) == ':' || tgt.charAt(0) == ';'
```

evaluates to the same value as

```
(tgt.length() <= 3 && tgt.charAt(0) == ':') || tgt.charAt(0) == ';'
```

(Notice the parentheses around `(... && ...)`)

If we want that the `||`-operator is evaluated first, we have to add explicit parentheses:

```
tgt.length() <= 3 && (tgt.charAt(0) == ':' || tgt.charAt(0) == ';')
```

(Notice the parentheses around `(... || ...)`)

(likewise with the 2nd `if`-condition)

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/4zFdy9)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your second if isn't correctly set.

If I understand correctly you want to check if the second letter is a ")" or a "D" unless the length is of two.

what your checking is if it's length = 2 and 2nd letter ")" OR that the second letter is simply equal to a "D"

you would fix it by changing the if to `if ((&& tgt.charAt(1) == ')'|| tgt.charAt(1) == 'D') && tgt.length() != 2) {`

Comment: It is not only the 2nd `if`, it's the 1st as well.